# Предварительный просмотр PDF файла, перед скачиванием. Как сделать?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, sql-server, ssrs

Использую SQL Reporting services 2012.
    "http://127.0.0.1/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/newreport&rs:Format=PDF&Name=ulan"

По этой ссылке грузится готовый, сформированный отчет в формате pdf. А можно ли перед скачиванием, сделать предварительный просмотр этого файла? Типа на печать, либо скачать.

Comment: Чтобы предварительно просмотреть, надо сначала скачать к себе то, что будете предварительно смотреть. Ну так...

Answer (score 1):

Думаю  будет хорошим решением, так же они принимает параметры вывода такие как width и height
делал так недавно, выводите мелкое окно или в ссылку в _target="blank" и там уже передавайте  а перед ним ссылку на скачивание хотя  позволяет скачать уже в браузере в просмотре и распечатать тоже.
 открывает файл PDF в браузере прямо.

Comment: Не подходит. Так как та ссылка которая я указал, при переходе на нее рисует pdf формат. а тег embed как я понял, надо там указать адресс, где хранится это файл.

Comment: установите embed после формирования файла и все будет работать

Comment: @Дмитрий  после формирования это тогда когда уже скачался?

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать пред просмотр, то зачем сразу скачивать. Сформируйте файл, пользователь посмотрит и после скачает. Темболее, что в embed есть функция скачивания. К сожалению я не вижу Ваш код.

Comment: @Дмитрий вот я же говорю нету пока что этого файла, использую SQL Reporting services, которая делает отчет, и возвращает в pdf формате. Этот файл, пока что как обьект.

Comment: Все равно же возвращается pdf или я что-то ни так понял?

Comment: @Дмитрий да возвращает pdf.

Comment: Ну вот вам и ответ, вам не нужно скачивание, после возврата pdf используйте embed и все. Пользователь сам определит нужно ли ему скачивать или нет

Comment: @Дмитрий <embed src="http://127.0.0.1/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/newreport&rs:Format=PDF&Name=ulan" width="500" height="375" 
 type='application/pdf'>  вот так?

Comment: Так врятли отработает (в зависимости от кода). Но в самой страничке где у Вас загрузка файла в конце установите тэг. То есть как то так: идет код формирования, а после него embed

Comment: @Дмитрий  а там кнопка печати будет?

Comment: Да, основные функции там есть (пример который нашел в интеренете: http://fast.ulmart.ru/manuals/3623638.pdf)

Comment: @Дмитрий +100 в карме.

Comment: Все получилось?

Comment: Если да не забудьте оценить ответ

Comment: @Дмитрий пробую сейчас

Comment: Кнопка печати будет в самом открытом файле на странице в правом углу. То что Вы указываете локалку это может не сработать, пропишите правильный путь папки сайта до файла

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то используйте тег `<embed>` (http://htmlbook.ru/html/embed)